# How to persist Google App Engine PHP sessions beyond shared memcache?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using standard PHP session stuff for my web app, which means session data is stored in App Engine's shared memcache. Google's docs state that this can get flushed so any logged in user sessions would fail. How exactly do I add use of Datastore (or Cloud Storage - which would be best?) into this process so that memcache is still used unless it gets flushed in which case Datastore is referred to? Is there a way to do this that minimises Datastore reads & writes and thus minimises cost and latency? I'm ideally after code (or even pseudocode) or even better a drop-in library or class :)

Or, is a flush of the shared memcache so unlikely that it doesn't really matter?

Many thanks.

Comment: Shared memcache does get flushed regularly. I have a Datastore session handler I might open source

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info, was wondering how likely the flush was. Yes, if you  to open source the handler that would obviously be a great help :) Much appreciating your php-gds at the moment I have to say!

Comment: Good to hear, glad it's useful.